# Stream microphone input from mobile browser to speakers connected to a RPi on the same WiFi

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, web-audio-api

How does one get started streaming live audio from a mobile browser to an raspberry pi (to which, speakers are connected) on the same WiFi network.?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend NOT trying to roll your own low-level streaming code.  WebRTC should cover this scenario, and there's at least one WebRTC library for Raspberry Pi (Janus).  This would cope with all the streaming difficulties for you.